# MySQL crash on DROP FUNCTION

Tags: c++, mysql

I have created a UDF through the `CREATE FUNCTION` command, and now when I try to drop it the server crashes. According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-function-udf.html), this is a known issue:

> To upgrade the shared library associated with a UDF, issue a DROP FUNCTION statement, upgrade the shared library, and then issue a CREATE FUNCTION statement. If you upgrade the shared library first and then use DROP FUNCTION, the server may crash.

It does, indeed, crash, and afterwards any attempt to remove the function crashes, even if I completely remove the DLL from the plugin directory. During development I'm continually replacing the library that defines the UDF functions. I've already re-installed MySQL from scratch once today and would rather not do it again. Aside from being more careful, is there anything I can do to e.g. clean up the mysql.* tables manually so as to remove the function?

Edit: after some tinkering, the database seems to have settled into a pattern of crashing until I have removed the offending DLL, and after that issuing `Error Code: 1305: FUNCTION [schema].[functionName] does not exist`. If I attempt to drop the function as root, I get the same message but without the schema prefix.

`SELECT * from mysql.func` shows the function. If I remove the record by hand, I get the same 1305 error.

Comment: Have you reported the bug to MySQL and tried a different version?

Comment: @Dai AFAICT it's in the documentation for all version 5 releases. I'm going to go out on a limb assume they know about it, and that it's not an issue fixed in a recent version. I happen to be on MariaDB 10.1.19.

Comment: Remove the record by hand and then restart the mysql server service?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I had not tried restarting the service after removing the record manually, this did in fact resolve the issue. Thanks! If you want to make a reply to that effect I will accept it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the data in the system tables in the `mysql` schema is cached in memory on first touch.  After that, modifying the tables by hand may not have the expected effect unless the server is restarted.

For the grant tables, a mechanism for flushing any cached data is provided -- `FLUSH PRIVILIGES` -- but for other tables, like `func` and the time zone tables, the only certain way to ensure that manual changes to the tables are all taken into consideration is to restart the server process.